# Divs overlapping

Tags: html, css

So what I am trying to do is make a horizontal list, but instead of using ul and li. I trying to align divs. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmo3brtq/)

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="img/toxiic-logo.jpg" alt="ToXiiC Avitar" style="width: 100%" />
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>ToXiiC</b></h4>
        <p>Founder and CTO</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align divs horizontally, use [CSS-Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
Create a parent element containing the divs with CSS

```
display: flex;
flexflow: row wrap;     /* or no-wrap instead of wrap, if you want to make 100% sure, they are all in the same row, even if they don't really fit */
justify-content: space-around;
```

and remove the absolute positioning form `.card`:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

this should do it.

Comment: It just deformed my card by extending the height a lot

Comment: @Its_ToXiiC what do you mean?  Are you trying to display multiple divs of class "container" next to each other, or multiple cards?  
If it deforms your content, there likely isnt enough space available.

Comment: Multiple cards. The card in the JSFiddle I want to make multiple go horizontal.

Comment: @Its_ToXiiC remove the lines `
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
from .card in css and make sure, you have applied the code, i gave to you, to a parent div, not to the cards themselves. It works for me, tested in your JSFiddle

Comment: the card is the parent div.

Comment: @Its_ToXiiC but if you want to distribute the cards horizontally, you are gonna need a parent div, they are inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125258/discussion-between-syntac-and-its-toxiic).